# How to deny POST to a url in nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, botnet

Some of the SQL-heavy URL on my app (say `/members`) are being attacked by botnets. So I'd like to disable anybody to post to these URL, while allowing others to GET them.

I tried to make a nested loop like this:

```
if ($request_uri ~ .*members^)  {

   if ($request_method = POST ) {
         return 444;
     }
}
```

But nginx does not accept this.

I also tried this directive

```
location ~ "^/members$" {
    if ($request_method ~ ^(POST)$ ) {       
        return 444;
    }
}
```

but this one deny GET too.

So left clueless and appreciate your help.

Comment: You don't need regex for this btw.

Comment: I know. I also tried with request_method = POST. It made no difference.

Comment: if is evil ... See this : https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
location ^~ /members {
  limit_except GET {
    deny  all;
  }
}
```

Deny all requests except `GET`.

Comment: This has the same effect as my second config, i.e. denies both GET and POSTs.

Comment: No it doesn't. Post your **whole** configuration.

Comment: Works perfectly for me