# Nginx - Block all non GET or POST requests

Tags: nginx

Quite often i can see following request in nginx access log with 400 response code:

```
23.124.177.223 - - [26/May/2018:19:19:59 +0200] "\x97\x00\x00\x00G\xA0\x0B\xC9\xD2\x9C5\x95\xBF\x14\x8F\xEBj\xC8\x0EOqP\x09\xDB.\x8B\x1F\x8F3\x1C'\xA1pg\x22\xB9J\x19IFd\xFD\xC9L\x18z\xA3\xEE\x9AQ\x04\xD6\x22\x13]\xD4\xFD\xF03\x88'\xCC\xDB\x0F+\xC3{Ulds\x00\xA6\x10o\xD9\xFFMO\xA0\x08XL\xE1\xDE\xCA\xDB\x98\xAF\xB9\xE5\xAEU\xFB\x1B\xFD\x8F\x07\x0Bne\x03@\x16b4{\x958\xA8\x19\xD0&\x0E\x7F\x97SJ\x9E\x9F7\x7F\x8D\xC7\xCE\xD4+\xAA\x86%\x8F#\xEEB\x98G\x08\x13\x12\x06\xFDc/8\xC6\x8Dw\xFB\xBB\xBC\x97\xB9\xB9\xB3\xE2" 400 173 "-" "-"
```

Im aware it's automated vulnerability scanner, but im not sure what type of requests is and why nginx response with `400`.

I already have following condition:

```
if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD)$ ) {
return 444; }
```

Is it a `HEAD`, any solution avoiding regex and yet blocking it (returning `444`) ?

`nginx -v 1.10.3`

Comment: You should avoid using IF in Nginx - Google "Nginx if is evil" for details. For a better way see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/637908/how-to-deny-post-to-a-url-in-nginx)

Comment: Agree, but this condition is used outside `location` directive.

Comment: If you have high scale, and it doesn't perform as well as you expect, you may want to review your config for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a request type at all. The `400 Bad Request` is  correct response for *malformed request syntax*. This error happens before your condition gets tested, being the reason you'd never see the (Nginx expanded error code) `444 No Response` from your `if` directive.

Comment: Hmm, at the end, it's treated like request, malformed or not. So any ideas to return different response?

Comment: Possibly with `error_page 400 =444 /444.html`, but **why?**